# How to investigate for mail not sent/received

Tags: email, smtp, send-to, asp

I've got a classic ASP page that sends emails to registered users.

From one month to date, some users which have their emails on 3 specific domains, are not receiving emails. Some others with their emails on the same 3 specific domains receive their emails without problems.

My ISP does noticed nothing strange and says that what I'm doing to send emails is correct. This is my email sender configuration:

```
dim email
set email=server.CreateObject("aspSmartMail.SmartMail")
email.Server="localhost"
email.ContentType = "text/html"
...
```

How can I investigate to understand what is sometimes going wrong?

Comment: Do you get a bounce message? Have you asked the users to check their spam folders/configuration?

Comment: No, I don't get a bounce message. My costumer says that he has checked spam folder with some users that doesn't received the mail, but there was nothing. The ISP says that there in nothing strange...

Comment: Then there is not enough information to diagnose your problem.

Comment: I'm asking more details to the ISP... I'll let you know if I can obtain useful information.